# Calling a function passing a Type parameter issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, types

In a Class I've written some methods to retrieve some files, and now to simplify code writting I've written this private function which expects a Type:

```
Private Shared Function GetDeletedItems(Of T)(Optional ByVal DriveLetter As Char = Nothing) As T()

    Return (From Item As ShellObject In RecycleBin
            Where Item.GetType = GetType(T) _
                  AndAlso If(DriveLetter = Nothing,
                             Nothing,
                             Item.Name.StartsWith(DriveLetter,
                                                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).
            Cast(Of T).
            ToArray()

End Function
```

Then only this public function should be called from the class, where I try to set the right Type to call the private function and return the data:

```
Public Shared Function GetDeletedItems(ByVal ItemType As ShellItemType,
                                       Optional ByVal DriveLetter As Char = Nothing)

    Dim CurrentType As Type = Nothing

    Select Case ItemType

        Case ShellItemType.All
            CurrentType = GetType(ShellObject)

        Case ShellItemType.Files
            CurrentType = GetType(ShellFile)

        Case ShellItemType.Folders
            CurrentType = GetType(ShellFolder)

    End Select

    Return GetDeletedItems(Of CurrentType)(DriveLetter)

End Function
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error at the Return instruction 'cause it says that the `CurrentType` is not defined, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Type` is `System.Type` which is different from `Of T` which is "Type Parameter", type parameter needs to be known at compiletime

Comment: thanks for comment, but then which modifications I need to make? a type parameter can't be defined in a var like I'm trying to do with a type?

Comment: @ElektroStudios, you're going to have to use reflection to build the right generic type at runtime. I can write it in C#, but it would take me a long time in VB so I probably can't help as much as I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first place you don't need a variable `CurrentType`, Compiler will not be happy to compile that. Get rid of that.

Does this meet your requirements?

```
Public Shared Function GetDeletedItems(ByVal ItemType As ShellItemType,
                                       Optional ByVal DriveLetter As Char = Nothing)
    Select Case ItemType

        Case ShellItemType.All
            Return  GetDeletedItems(Of ShellObject)(DriveLetter)
        Case ShellItemType.Files
            Return  GetDeletedItems(Of ShellFile)(DriveLetter)
        Case ShellItemType.Folders
            Return  GetDeletedItems(Of ShellFolder)(DriveLetter)
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: yes calling everytime the Return was my other alternative but is not what I've asked for, anyways thankyou so much. +1

Comment: @ElektroStudios Yes I know that, but what you asked for is not possible:(

Comment: Am pretty sure that's not possible. Wait for better answer, if one accept it :)

Comment: I hope that I don't offended you, sorry just I was not sure of what you've wanted to mean with "it's not possible", my english is not good, thanks again

Comment: @ElektroStudios Never, infact to show symbolically that am not offended I used `:)`happy smiley. cheers, you can happily accept another answer if anyone comes with better one. btw my english also not good :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I'm not seeing the reason to split into two functions.  I think your outer function should be the generic one, you should kill the ShellItemType altogether.

The method would simply be your inner private method, only you'd make it public:

```
Public Shared Function GetDeletedItems(Of T)(Optional ByVal DriveLetter As Char = Nothing) As T()

    Return (From Item As ShellObject In RecycleBin
            Where Item.GetType = GetType(T) _
                  AndAlso If(DriveLetter = Nothing,
                             Nothing,
                             Item.Name.StartsWith(DriveLetter,
                                                  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).
            Cast(Of T).
            ToArray()

End Function
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
Dim results = GetDeletedItems(Of ShellObject)(driveLetter)
```

It appears that you are setting the ShellItemType variable outside of the method based on the type, so you could actually just sent that type itself in.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I know I could call directly the private function as you've written in your example but I've liked to add an Enum to use it in the public function just to remember the Interfaces that I could use (ShellObject, ShellItem, ShellFolder, ShellLink) it's more easy for me to remember them. thankyou +1